# how to embed a span tag in a list iteration in vue

Tags: vuejs2

New to vuejs and I would like to be able to output something like

```
<div>
  <span>
      item 1  
      item 2
  </span>
  <span>
     item 3
     item 4
  </span>
</div>
```

I have tried with the following but doesn't seem to work. I think th issue is the `<span>` tag and straight text works fine. How would I make Vuejs output a span or is there a different way to achieve this?

```
      <div v-for="(item,idx) in selectedItems">
        <span v-if="(idx % 2) == 0" v-html="rawHtml"><span></span>
        {{item.display_name}}
        <span v-if="((idx-1) % 2) == 0" v-html="rawHtml"></span></span>
      </div>
```

Comment: How about getting a more suitable data structure?

Comment: hmm... no need for more of a data structure - but i suspect that's the only workaround

Comment: If it's a regular array, I think, it's possible to get desired result without modification of data structure.

Comment: hmm... thx - yeah, was hoping so but just doesn't seem to work. I'll probably do as a computed property like `selectedItemsCols` or something. thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Try next variant:

```
<div>
    <span v-for="(item, idx) in selectedItems"
          v-if="idx % 2 === 0">
        <p>{{item.display_name}}</p>
        <p v-if="selectedItems[idx + 1]">{{selectedItems[idx + 1].display_name}}</p>
    </span>
</div>
```